# Accessing an AWS requester pays bucket (usage for arxiv.org)

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have tried a few programs to try to locate and download the arxiv.org requester pays bucket, but no success.
I emailed arxiv.org for help, but no response.
How the HECK to do this on Windows 7x64?
Does anyone have or know of a step-by-step tutorial on how to access third party requester pays buckets?  I am willing to make one and post on here and on Youtube if I can just get started...

The details I am trying to follow are on:

http://arxiv.org/help/bulk_data_s3

I tried various programs (s3browser, bucketexplorer, cloudberry) with no success. It appears the requester pays buckets require more specific details to locate that the arxiv.org website is not providing.

Now I have installed amazon cli

My credentials are entered and I have confirmed that I can access my account buckets, created a couple of folders, and have sent and received a few files.

When I try to locate the arxiv.org requester pays bucket:

```
aws s3 ls s3://arxiv.s3.amazonaws.com/pdf/
```

I get the response:

A client error (NoSuchBucket) occurred when calling the ListObjects operation: 
The specified bucket does not exist

I also tried:

```
aws s3 ls --add-header="x-amz-request-payer:requester" ls s3:/
/arxiv/pdf/arXiv_pdf_manifest.xml
```

I get the responseL

```
Unknown options: --add-header=x-amz-request-payer:requester,s3://arxiv/pdf/arXiv
_pdf_manifest.xml
```

I tried:

```
aws get "x-amz-request-payer:requester" arxiv/pdf/arXiv_pdf_1001_001.tar > arXiv_pdf_1001_001.tar
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [parameters]
aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

autoscaling                              | cloudformation

etc etc
```

Also tried:

```
C:\z_amazonAWScli>aws s3 "x-amz-request-payer:requester" ls s3://arxiv/pdf/
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [parameters]
aws: error: argument subcommand: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

ls                                       | website

etc etc
```

Several other variations, no response.
  Thanks in advance, 
               miniscule

Running aws s3 ls shows me my account folders. 
Running aws s3 ls s3://arxiv/pdf/arXiv_pdf_manifest.xml
gives me 
A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Short answer no what your asking isn't allowed here, though there are a number of websites where you can hire a coder to get it done and/or provide technical explanations of how they did it.

Comment: However if you posted a specific question about an area you were having trouble with and provided a detailed explanation of what you having trouble with AND what you have done so far Im sure you would quickly find the help you needed (and for free!)

Comment: ok I modified the original question - - does what I have done so far make any sense?

Answer (score 3):

Let us to work on these errors one by one.

- For the first error for command `aws s3 ls s3://arxiv.s3.amazonaws.com/pdf/`, that meaning you didn't set permission properly. Please login management console to check the permission. If can, could you please run the command `aws s3 ls`, do you get any buckets listed?
- for the second command `aws s3 ls --add-header="x-amz-request-payer:requester" ls s3:/
  /arxiv/pdf/arXiv_pdf_manifest.xml`, the error gives the reason, `Unknown options`, and check in github https://github.com/aws/aws-cli, there is no this option `--add-header`
- For the third command `aws get`, it should follow with the subcommand, which you missed.

Here is the help output for `aws get`

```
$ aws get help
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [parameters]
aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

autoscaling                              | cloudformation
cloudfront                               | cloudsearch
cloudsearchdomain                        | cloudtrail
cloudwatch                               | cognito-identity
cognito-sync                             | datapipeline
directconnect                            | dynamodb
ec2                                      | elasticache
elasticbeanstalk                         | elastictranscoder
elb                                      | emr
iam                                      | importexport
kinesis                                  | kms
lambda                                   | logs
opsworks                                 | rds
redshift                                 | route53
route53domains                           | sdb
ses                                      | sns
sqs                                      | storagegateway
sts                                      | support
swf                                      | s3api
s3                                       | configure
deploy                                   | configservice
help
```

The last command seems similar error which you run the command with wrong formation. Please DO review the awscli document first, especially s3 part.

[Using Amazon S3 with the AWS Command Line Interface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-s3.html)

Comment: Running aws s3 ls shows me my account folders. Running aws s3 ls s3://arxiv/pdf/arXiv_pdf_manifest.xml
gives me 
A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied

Comment: how about `aws s3 ls s3://arxiv.s3.amazonaws.com/pdf/arXiv_pdf_manifest.xml` ?

Answer (score -1):

How to gain access to a requester pays bucket on Amazon AWS

Create an Amazon AWS account and make sure a working credit card is in the account billing settings.

Download s3browser 
http://s3browser.com/

CTRL-SHIFT-A to add your Amazon account credentials

Create a new bucket to put files in. 
Upload a file to test that the folder is functional.
Type CTRL-E to add an External Bucket (under "Buckets" in the top menu).

Enter arxiv/pdf in the "bucket name" field, then click "Add External Bucket"

This will not work on the first connection attempt.
After about 30 seconds the program dialog will ask:
Would you like to try this bucket as a requester pays bucket?
Select Yes
The connection will retry, and after a brief refresh, you should see the arxiv/pdf folder populate...

Hope this helps others navigate the ridiculously frustrating requester pays bucket gauntlet. 
Have a happy new year and thanks again for your help guys...